Spark not using custom JDBCDialect in pyspark
I have trouble upgrading to spark 3.5.0 from our current enviroment (3.1.2) on databricks.
We have a custom dialect defined for our connection to a SQL Server as we are using different datatypes as definied in the default dialect. Our testing so far with the custom dialect worked fine even writing TimestampTypes as datetime2 until a limit clause is send because the query contains LIMIT 10001 instead of TOP 10001.
The custom dialect is defined in scala as:
#custom_dialect.scala
package de.company.test.utils

...imports...

class Datetime2MsSqlServerDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean =
    url.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).startsWith("jdbc:sqlserver")

  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
    case TimestampType => Some(JdbcType("DATETIME2", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP))
    case TimestampNTZType =>
      Some(JdbcType("DATETIME2", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP))
    case StringType  => Some(JdbcType("NVARCHAR(MAX)", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR))
    case BooleanType => Some(JdbcType("BIT", java.sql.Types.BIT))
    case BinaryType =>
      Some(JdbcType("VARBINARY(MAX)", java.sql.Types.VARBINARY))
    case ShortType if !SQLConf.get.legacyMsSqlServerNumericMappingEnabled =>
      Some(JdbcType("SMALLINT", java.sql.Types.SMALLINT))
    case _ => None
  }

  override def getLimitClause(limit: Integer): String = {
    if (limit > 0) s"TOP ($limit)" else ""
  }

  ...
}

Since we use pyspark on databricks we registered the custom dialect as follows:
 spark_builder = SparkSession.builder.appName(self.app_name).config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
 spark_session = spark_builder.getOrCreate()

 if DatabricksUtils.is_running_on_databricks_cluster():
     self.__register_custom_jdbc_dialect(spark_session.sparkContext)

 def __register_custom_jdbc_dialect(self, spark_context):
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

    gw = spark_context._gateway
    java_import(gw.jvm, "de.company.test.utils.Datetime2MsSqlServerDialect")
    gw.jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(
        gw.jvm.de.company.test.utils.Datetime2MsSqlServerDialect()
    )

Now if we run our notebooks with a display() or some other function which includes a limit, spark appends LIMIT  instead of adding TOP .
Some checks I did made me believe that this aspect of the custom dialect isnt getting used:
> spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(spark._jvm.de.company.test.utils.Datetime2MsSqlServerDialect())  
> spark._jvm.de.company.test.utils.Datetime2MsSqlServerDialect().getLimitClause(10)
TOP (10)

> spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.get("jdbc:sqlserver").getClass().getName()
'org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.AggregatedDialect'

> spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.get("jdbc:sqlserver").getLimitClause(10)  
'LIMIT 10'

I have tried countless ways to include the custom dialect and get both limits and the datatype conversion going but currenty I am at a loss where I went wrong.

Ways I tested untill now: Registering the dialect in scala, adding a register method to the class, leaving out the methods, different ways of importing the class and registering in pyspark. All without success.
